How can I run a Flutter application on past iOS versions?
Edit: My initial problem was due to the problem Flutter failed to build ios app, unsupported option -G for target. With the solution provided on the link I didn't need to downgrade de iOS SDK version.
My project uses Flutter version 3.22.3 and some packages are not compatible with the latest version of iOS, which is iOS 18.0. So I downgraded the iOS version of my Xcode to iOS 17.0 that I know the app can run on.
I'm getting the following error:
iOS 18.0 is not installed. To download and install the platform, open
Xcode, select Xcode \> Settings \> Platforms, and click the GET button for the
required platform.

For more information, please visit:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.\

I can run the app on the latest versions of Android and this is how I'm debbuging, but I'll eventually need to test it on iOS.
I've researched for it and could not find a solution to run a Flutter app on a previous iOS version.

There are three things you need to consider; the iOS SDK you are using to build. You may as well switch to the iOS 18 SDK now; this will let you use Xcode 16 and Apple will require this SDK by around March next year. The second is the lowest version of iOS that your app supports; you set this in the Xcode project. I would suggest ios 15 or 16 is a reasonable choice these days,  but you could go as low as iOS 13. Finally you may have some packages that have a minimum version requirement depending on the API calls they use. This will affect your minimum iOS support  choice

If you do want to build against the iOS 17 SDK while Apple still allows this, you need to select this api in your Xcode project build settings

@Paulw11 I believe the issues I'm having with iOS 18.0 are caused by the lack of support for this SDK in some packages I use. Maybe it is too recent for me to use it. Almost all the problems are coming from Firebase packages.

I would be very surprised if the SDK itself caused an issue. You should [edit] your question to show the errors you are getting.  If the only error you are getting is the one shown in your question,  you need to run Xcode and download the iOS 18 SDK

@Paulw11 these issues I must ask in another question. This one was about the ability to use a previous iOS SDK version. Thank you!

Just follow this:

open Xcode, select Xcode > Settings > Platforms, and click the GET
button for the required platform.

It's just saying to install iOS 18 only and after installation simulator will star working. You can change the iOS version settings to 17 later on.

Just update: open Xcode -> Xcode (menu) -> Settings -> Components. Install platform that you want.

It seems that I'm only able to use previous versions of iOS SDK if I also have the most updated version.
